# Password max length and char set policy - OWASP, dropbox, sha512, bcrypt, ASCII and unicode

Tags: unicode, passwords, ascii, dropbox, owasp

**Please note this post is about acceptable max password length and characters only and not other security measures such as min length, pwned, zxcvbn, salts etc**

Reference: -
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html#implement-proper-password-strength-controls

https://dropbox.tech/security/how-dropbox-securely-stores-your-passwords

So OWASP recommends that password length be " not be set too low, as it will prevent users from creating passphrases" and to allow "usage of all characters including unicode and whitespace. ".
OWASP also correctly points out that certain encryption algorithms have byte limits, in the case of bcrypt this is 72 bytes.

And ASCII char has 1 byte, a unicode char has 1-4 bytes. This makes a limitation on the number of chars accepted in an input field to be functionally useless, as you would have to take into account a max length for the possibility of a password consisting of unicode chars which could be up to 4 bytes.

[Some have argued](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/177709) that unicode is error-prone due to bugs. I assume this is related to storage only? Can someone can correct me on this if I am wrong? So if it is storage-only, I would assume that dropbox's method of converting the incoming password to a sha512 hash prior to encrypting with bcrypt (in order to create a 64 byte string, below the bcrypt length threshold) would eliminate this?

So this would lead to the following recommendation: -

1. No max limit on password length
2. No restrictions on char sets
3. Create a sha512 hash from the password to eliminate potential unicode bugs and bcrypt max length issues
4. Have bcrypt encrypt the password hash as opposed to the password itself

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox's approach is relatively sound, in that it addresses the valid constraints you have enumerated. It also does so in a way that handles [bcrypt's null problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence) by using the ASCII representation of the SHA512 hash.

However, it does have one notable flaw: the "[hash shucking](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/234795/6203)" problem (disclosure - my answer). Raw hashes can be cracked faster outside the bcrypt hash once they are discovered. This is a tricky concept, so experimenting with an example to understand it better is encouraged.

The additional mitigation that covers this would be to add a static salt ('pepper') to the inner hash, stored separately from the hash layer using an HSM or similar.

Comment: BTW both OWASP and NIST are recommending a max of 64 chars on passwords. There seems to be no practical reason for this aside from protecting against DDoS from bcrypting a huge password, which is guarded against in the scenario above.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to a HSM, AWS Secrets Manager would be the closest I could do. Right now I am looking into Argon2id.